# Why does the array have an extra "[index] => " in the end, and array_combine error

Tags: php, arrays, warnings, associative-array

I am using `array_combine()` function on two arrays, and using the following **code**:

```
if (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of CSV elements
    print_r($line);
    print_r($slots_for_quiz);
    $combined_array = array_combine($slots_for_quiz, $line);
    print_r($combined_array); //check 
} else {echo 'FALSE';}
```

The **output** is:

```
Array ( [0] => Alpha [1] => Beta [2] => Gamma [3] => )  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 
Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements
```

So we can see that **`$line`** is: Array ( [0] => Alpha [1] => Beta [2] => Gamma **[3] =>** )

and **`$slots_for_quiz`** is: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )

**My question is
 1. Why am I getting `[3] =>` in the end of `$line` (this is not even an associative array).
 2. About the warning: why does it say that my arrays do not have same number of elements. Both of them have `3` elements, isn't it?**

Comment: Maybe posting your CSV file is a good idea.

Comment: @LéoLam  `Alpha,Beta,Gamma,` Thank you for pointing out, I think it is the last `,` which is the culprit. Just going to check it

Comment: Yes, PHP seems to consider the CSV as containing 4 "values": Alpha, Beta, Gamma and an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like:

```
$line = array_filter($line);
$combined_array = array_combine($slots_for_quiz, $line);
```

Should remove that empty value, and probably line it up now correctly.

Or you could just pop it.

```
array_pop($line);
$combined_array = array_combine($slots_for_quiz, $line);
```